# TSQL JSON How to add an array to an existing Json Object?

Tags: json, t-sql

We've got a SQL query where we create a JSON file with for JSON Path.
We want to merge 2 JSON objects into 1 JSON. But we struggle with the code how to accomplish this task.

We tried JSON_MODIFY to merge them together using append. But this did not work for us.

What we'd like to do is this, we have 2 seperate json objects and we want to merge them as one.

Json Object A:

```
{
    "ID" : 0,
    "Name" : "a name",
    "Description" : "a description"
}
```

and Json Object B

```
"Nodes" : [
    {
        "NodeID" : 10,
        "NodeName" : "Node 0"
    },
    {
        "NodeID" : 11,
        "NodeName" : "Node 1"
    }
]
```

What we want to have:

```
{
    "ID" : 0,
    "Name" : "a name",
    "Description" : "a description",
    "Nodes" : [
        {
            "NodeID" : 10,
            "NodeName" : "Node 0"
        },
        {
            "NodeID" : 11,
            "NodeName" : "Node 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Our current SQL Query looks like this:

```
set @JsonCourse = ( select c.name, c.id, c.description from dbo.courses c where c.id = @id for json path)

set @JsonNodes = ( select n.id, n.name from dbo.nodes n where n.courseId = @id for json path, root('Nodes'))

set @CompleteJson =  JSON_MODIFY(@JsonCourse,'append $',JSON_QUERY(@JsonNodes));

print @CompleteJson
```

But our result is like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID" : 0,
        "Name" : "a name",
        "Description" : "a description" 
    },
    {
        "Nodes" : [
            {
                "NodeID" : 10,
                "NodeName" : "Node 0"
            },
            {
                "NodeID" : 11,
                "NodeName" : "Node 1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Note:** we've used hypothetical data here.

How do we fix this with JSON_MODIFY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll add another answer, as this is a completely different thing as the first answer:

As I do not have your tables, I'll set the JSON variables to the values you provided

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "ID" : 0,
    "Name" : "a name",
    "Description" : "a description"
}'

DECLARE @json2 NVARCHAR(MAX)= --<-- had to add the surrounding {}, otherwise this was invalid JSON
N'{"Nodes" : 
[
    {
        "NodeID" : 10,
        "NodeName" : "Node 0"
    },
    {
        "NodeID" : 11,
        "NodeName" : "Node 1"
    }
]}';
```

--We do not need `append` here.
--We have to tell the engine the name of the new node.
--To avoid repeated key `Nodes` I read from the `@json2` using `$.Nodes` as path

```
DECLARE @CompleteJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=JSON_MODIFY(@Json1,'$.Nodes',JSON_QUERY(@Json2,'$.Nodes'));

PRINT @CompleteJSON;
```

I hope this is closer to your needs...

Comment: Yes this is exactly what we need, thanks a lot for the explanation! Now I understand JSON_MODIFY better

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [creating a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is a *stand-alone* sample, which makes your issue reproducible, and helps us to provide easy answers...

If I got this correctly there is a `1:n` related structure, where each node in your "object A" can have several nodes in "object B".

My following code will simulate this through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Each table as 1 or many columns.

We solve this with a *correlated sub-query*. This is the way to create nested JSON arrays:

```
SELECT TOP 3 t.TABLE_NAME AS NodeName
            ,t.TABLE_TYPE AS NodeType
            ,(
                SELECT TOP 3 c.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName
                            ,c.DATA_TYPE AS ColumnType 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
                WHERE c.TABLE_CATALOG=t.TABLE_CATALOG
                 AND  c.TABLE_SCHEMA=t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                 AND  c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME
                FOR JSON PATH
             ) AS MyColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The result

```
[
    {
        "NodeName": "spt_fallback_db",
        "NodeType": "BASE TABLE",
        "MyColumns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "xserver_name",
                "ColumnType": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_ins",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_last_ins_upd",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "NodeName": "spt_fallback_dev",
        "NodeType": "BASE TABLE",
        "MyColumns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "xserver_name",
                "ColumnType": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_ins",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_last_ins_upd",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "NodeName": "spt_fallback_usg",
        "NodeType": "BASE TABLE",
        "MyColumns": [
            {
                "ColumnName": "xserver_name",
                "ColumnType": "varchar"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_ins",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            },
            {
                "ColumnName": "xdttm_last_ins_upd",
                "ColumnType": "datetime"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, each table as a nested set of columns, represented through a JSON array.

Comment: Thanks, right perhaps there was some information missing in our main post.
We have lots of split tables to split data. This was just a reconstructed minimalized example. We have 2 json objects that we want to merge, thats the main question.
Each node could contain different data.
Hence we have 2 different json objects that we want to merge into 1 using JSON_MODIFY